# Interfacing with tensorflow model results in an error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm currently using DNN regressor with 11 input neurons multiple hidden layers, and 11 output neurons.
I've have finished training the model. However, when I try to interface with the model with this code:

```
 a = np.array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
    y_pred = regressor.predict(a, as_iterable=False) 
    print(y_pred)
```

However this generates an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 11 values, but the requested shape has 121
         [[node dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/X/Reshape (defined at regressor_full.py:177) ]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regressor_full.py", line 206, in <module>
    a = np.array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted.
```

I'm just trying to generate a prediction for 11 input variables and predict 11 output variables(as I trained the model), however, it generates an error.
I've tried changing the as_iterable to True, however this doesn't change anything. What is currently causing the error, and how do I fix it? Thank you for your time.

As requested, I included the code that defines the model.

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow

regressor = skflow.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                label_dimension=11,
                hidden_units=hidden_layers,
                model_dir=MODEL_PATH,
                dropout=dropout,
                config=test_config,
                activation_fn = tf.nn.relu,
                optimizer  = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your code to define the model. What class is the regressor?

Comment: Thank you for your response: Here is my repo.  https://github.com/itisyeetimetoday/reggression/blob/master/regressor_full.py
I will edit the question to include the code that defines my model.

Comment: @zihaozhihao are you still able to help?

Comment: Could you check your `feature_columns` in your code? It looks like your input feature should be 121, but you pass a 11-dim input tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the input array to **a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],dtype=" ")** and also define the dtype which might solve the issue.